# How to normalize comma separated values within column of table and then run query

Tags: mysql, csv, normalization

Let's say I have a table with the following structure:

```
 | column1    |    column2       |
 |------------|------------------|
 | a          |    1,L,3,K,5,    |
 | b          |    R,6,7,8,9     |
 | c          |    8,9,10,D      |
 | d          |    1,2,3,H       |
```

Let's say that column1 can potentially continue on through z and that column2 can continue on with random numbers and letters. I would like a general solution that can apply to any number of rows and columns, and number of values in column2.

I want to run a query in MySQL that will search all the values in column2 and output the letters in column1 that contain a 3 in column2. The output should be:

```
 | column1    |
 |------------|
 | a          | 
 | d          |
```

Many posts have answers with queries that directly accomplish this, but I would like to do it the correct way. I am new to sql, but I believe that would mean to normalize the data in column2 by creating a new table and running a query on this new table instead.

Can someone help me with the code to normalize and run this query in MySQL? Thanks.

Comment: Do you plan to permanently replace your table with a normalized one ?

Comment: No. I was hoping to keep the original table in tact.

Comment: Keeping the current table how it is will be a bad idea. With databases, you do not want multiple values in the same column. It can/will create problems down the road.

Comment: Alldayiwonder your table design is really bad.. although MySQL has a workaround for comma separated lists its still a VERY BAD IDEA... my answer is a working solution but I'll post how to normalize it in a minute

Comment: Normalizing a table just to run a query is just a waste of time.

Comment: True. I am looking for practice in the event I come across databases which I do not own that keep data in this way.

Comment: @sgeddes - Please look at the entire dialogue between me and OP. Starting with my question in the top line.  All I'm saying is that creating a normalized table just to run a query and discarding it afterwards is indeed a waste of time.

Comment: @PM77-1 -- fair enough, can't argue there.

Comment: @alldayiwonder look at [**my edit**](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26321317/2733506).. I posted a query that will return your data normalized

Comment: @PM77-1 - I see. Would you say FIND_IN_SET is the way to go then? In the case where one does not own the database for which they want to run the query on and so restructuring the original table is not an option.

Comment: @alldayiwonder I can 99% guarantee you that you will never see a table like this in production. And if you do find that 1%, run.

Comment: `FIND_IN_SET` should work fine for your example.

Answer (score 2):

you need to use `FIND_IN_SET()`

```
SELECT column1 FROM table WHERE FIND_IN_SET('3', column2);
```

[**Fiddle Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/585b63/1)

You should **NEVER** store data inside the table as a comma separated list... so if I were you I would consider separating it into rows

to normalize your database you can do a query like this... NOTE you need to know the number of pieces you have in column2..

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE IF NOT EXISTS normalized_table AS 
(   SELECT
      column1,
      SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(column2, ',', n.digit+1), ',', -1) column2
    FROM test
    JOIN(SELECT 0 digit UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT 3 UNION ALL SELECT 4) n
        ON LENGTH(REPLACE(column2, ',' , '')) <= LENGTH(column2)-n.digit
    ORDER BY column1, n.digit
);

DROP table test;
CREATE table test (column1 varchar(2), column2 varchar(2));
INSERT INTO test (column1, column2) 
SELECT column1, column2 FROM normalized_table;
```

[**NORMALIZED RESULTS**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d2379/1)

The JOIN with each digit is your key... if you have 6 items comma separated then union 0-5 digits to join on.

if you don't know how many there are then just run this to know how many numbers to union

```
SELECT MAX(LENGTH(REPLACE(column2, ',', ''))) FROM test;
```

Comment: Can normalization be done in the case where the number of pieces in column2 is unknown? I am going to revise the problem to keep it general.

Comment: @alldayiwonder yes but in that case you would need a stored procedure with a loop

Comment: @alldayiwonder if you look at the bottom of my answer I just edited with a way to determine how many comma separated items you have in your column 2... run that and it'll tell you how many unions you need to do :)

Answer (score 1):

To normalize this table, you would want to use a table consisting of two columns, with the primary key being both columns. It would look something like this:

```
| column1    |    column2       |
|------------|------------------|
| a          |    1             |
| a          |    3             |
| a          |    L             |
| b          |    R             |
| c          |    8             |
| d          |    3             |
```

Then you can use this simple query:

```
Select column1 from table where column2 = 3;
```

Comment: That makes sense. What code would accomplish the normalization?

Comment: Since your dataset is most likely small, I would delete everything from the table, modify the table as I described, then reload the data. You can also copy the table data to excel prior to the delete so you don't loose anything.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is old post but I thought I'd contribute since I needed to perform this exercise myself and this gave me some ideas.

Here is the solution I arrived at,  the proviso here is that the values in the comma delimited list were defined uniquely in another table:

```
create table `defined_values` (
  id int(11) not null auto_increment primary key,
  label varchar(12) not null,
  constraint `defined_values_uidx` unique (`label`)
) engine = innodb charset utf8;

create table `delimited_string` (
  id int(11) not null auto_increment primary key,
  `str_delim` varchar(32) not null
) engine = innodb charset utf8;

insert into `defined_values` (`label`) values
('YVR'),
('YEG'),
('YXJ'),
('YYC'),
('YMM')
;

insert into `delimited_string` (`str_delim`) values 
('YVR,YEG,YXJ,YYC,YMM')
;

select 
  v.`label` as `normalized` 
from 
  `delimited_string` s
  join `defined_values` v on (v.`label` = substring(s.`str_delim`, position(v.`label` in s.`str_delim`), length(v.`label`)))
```

;

// Yields:

```
+------------+
| normalized | 
+------------+
| YEG        |
| YMM        |
| YVR        |
| YXJ        |
| YYC        |
+------------+
```

5 rows in set (0.00 sec)

Answer (score 0):

```
select column1 from your_tab where 3 in (column2)
```

or you can use

```
select column1 from your_tab where column2 like '3,%' or column2 like '%,3' or column2 like '%,3,%' or column2=3
```

Comment: Can you add some description?