# Php shuffle 2 unique numbers

Tags: php, random, range, unique, shuffle

I got a database with users and numbers.

I built a shuffle and tried to randomly give a user a number, that worked.

Now I have the issue that I want to give the user 2 random numbers with shuffle which shall be unique.

Main Code looks like this:

```
    $numbers = range(0, $counts); // $counts are the number of users in my databse
    $numbers2 = range(0, $counts);
    shuffle($numbers);
    shuffle($numbers2);

    foreach($users as $user) {
        # Starts from 1 if higher than 52
        $uniqueRand  = (array_pop($numbers)+$currentWeek) % 52 + 1;
        $uniqueRand2 = (array_pop($numbers2)+$currentWeek) % 52 + 1;

        # tried something like this but did         
        while($uniqueRand == $uniqueRand2) {
            $numbers2 = range(0, $counts);
            shuffle($numbers2);
            $uniqueRand2 = (array_pop($numbers2)+$currentWeek) % 52+1;
        }

         ...# Storing in database
    }
```

Here a little sketch of the application

```
Users      |       numbers
__________________________
Frank      |  14, 24
Tim        |  21, 43
Tom        |  52, 6
Hanz       |  8,  3
Benjamin   |  5,  1
West       |  7,  6
Thompson   |  4,  9
.....
```

The first line of numbers 14,21,52... stand for $numbers and the second line for $numbers2, I want to create unique random values which do not repeat themselves, but how do I check if the $number do not repeat in the same line and are still vertical unique.

So for instance would something like this be wrong:

```
Users      |       numbers
_________________________
Frank      |       14, 14
```

Something like this would be wrong too:

```
Users      |       numbers
_________________________
Frank      |     14, 24
Tim        |     21, 14
Tom        |     14,  6
Hanz       |      8,  3
Benjamin   |      5,  14
West       |      14,  6
Thompson   |      4,  9
```

Comment: Please don't  tell me you're trying to make these number combinations unique so that you would later use them for identifying or for something similar?

Comment: nope that is not the propose of this :D

Comment: You sure you want to do that? You want to check if those numbers exist in the database while creating unique numbers to match against those without creating duplicates? If that's what the question is about, you're going to need someone who can answer this that knows their SQL like a "guru".

Comment: yeah I wonder for hours how to solve this, so you suggest sql to solve this?

Comment: Database normalization http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26321299/how-to-normalize-comma-separated-values-within-column-of-table-and-then-run-quer --- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization

Comment: you should separate the both column as number1 and number2 then you can use MySQL query to insert unique number vertically as well as row wise. You have to manage that in a query. Then you can use concat to get the result as comma separated values

Comment: I have seperated them in the database I just echo $number1, $number2