# optimizing insert query

Tags: sql, oracle, stored-procedures

I am trying to insert comma separated values in a global table. When data is large it's taking long time to process the data. I need to optimize my insert query, is there any other ways to achieve below insert statement for better optimization? Please check code below for more info. Appreciated for any help.

```
//my proc
emp_id in CLOB;


//insert statement
insert into Global_Emp_Tbl
with inputs(str) as(
select to_clob(emp_id)
from dual
),
temp_table(s, n, empid, st_pos, end_pos) as (
select ',' || str || ',', -1, null, null, 1
from inputs

union all
selct s, n+1, substr(s, st_pos, end_pos - st_pos),
end_pos + 1, instr(s, ',', 1, n+3)
from temp_table
where end_pos != 0
)
select empid from temp_table where empid is not null;
commit;

//using insert table in where clause
exists( select 1 from Global_Emp_Tbl gt  where e.id =gt.emp_id ) //joining with main table
```

Comment: It is usual to *avoid* CSV data in a database - it makes it more difficult to use.

Comment: @AndrewMorton how can I avoid it? i must send the data in proc to process/filter the data

Comment: [Add another table](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26321344/1115360).

Comment: @AndrewMorton I am very limited here, only thing I can do is create global temp table.

Comment: What is the datatype of  `Global_Emp_Tbl.emp_id`? Is it `VARCHAR2` or `CLOB`?

Answer (score 0):

You can use simple REGEXP_SUBSTR to achieve the same

```
    insert into Global_Emp_Tbl
    SELECT Regexp_substr(empid, '[^,]+', 1, LEVEL) AS empid
    FROM   (SELECT To_clob(emp_id) empid
            FROM   dual)
    CONNECT BY LEVEL <= Regexp_count(emp_id, '[^,]+');
    commit;
```

Also, one more suggestion try changing the below in your function

```
 select empid from temp_table where n > 0;
```

Comment: I think this will crash the application if empid is greater than 4000 bytes.

Comment: i tested both functions both crash on this condition rpad(1,1999,1)||','||rpad(1,1999,1)||','||rpad(1,1999,1)||','||rpad(1,1999,1)

Comment: I tested my query passing 20k id and it was successful, the bad part is it took me more than a min to process 20k id. I am passing empid as a string.

Comment: did u try to test it with regexp_substr

Comment: yes I did , it did not crash my application but the process was lot slow than my query. appreciated your effort

Comment: based on my testing found select empid from temp_table where n > 0; faster than empid not null check

Comment: thanks for your suggestion, i tried where n > 0 but I am getting data inconsistent type as I believe emp_id is CLOB not varchar.

Comment: the error looks strange to me may be your actual implementation is different

Answer (score 0):

Well I can't reporduce your problem in `Oracle Database 11g Express Edition Release 11.2.0.2.0 - 64bit Production`

This procedure provides the sample data, a CLOB csv list of the first N interger

```
create or replace function get_list(N NUMBER) return CLOB
as
 v_lst CLOB;
 i PLS_INTEGER;
BEGIN
  v_lst :='1';
  for  i  in 2 .. n loop
     v_lst :=v_lst||','||to_char(i);
  end loop;   
  return(v_lst);
END;
/
```

Note that the 5K parameter give approximately 20K long list.

```
select length(get_list(5000)) from dual;
23892
```

The parsing of this list in a global temporary table is done in *seconds* not in *minutes*. Here an example using your `SELECT`

```
SQL> set timi on;
SQL> create global temporary table csv_tbl
  2  ON COMMIT PRESERVE ROWS
  3  as
  4  with inputs(str) as(
  5  select get_list(5000)
  6  from dual
  7  ),
  8  temp_table(s, n, empid, st_pos, end_pos) as (
  9  select ',' || str || ',', -1, null, null, 1
 10  from inputs
 11  union all
 12  select s, n+1, substr(s, st_pos, end_pos - st_pos),
 13  end_pos + 1, instr(s, ',', 1, n+3)
 14  from temp_table
 15  where end_pos != 0
 16  )
 17  select  empid  from temp_table where empid is not null
 18  ;

Table created.

Elapsed: 00:00:01.35
```

So the most probably explanation is, that the most elapsed time is spend in the query with the `EXISTS` clause

```
exists( select 1 from Global_Emp_Tbl gt  where e.id =gt.emp_id )
```

Two problems come to my mind

1) The datatypes of the `EMP_ID` in the temporary table and in the `EMP` table differs, e.g. in temporary table it is `VARCHAR2`, in the `EMP` table `NUMBER` - this will **prohibit the use of the index** on the `EMP` table.

2) The missing object statistics on the global temporary table leads the `CBO` to an wrong *execution plan* and you **use the index** (*in a large nested loops*) where you **should use a full table scan**.